# Android color filter

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-drawable

I have a text view that's showing text colored like this:
R:100
G:100
B:120

Now, when that text view slides under a certain control (let's call it View "A"), i would like to apply some color filter that will, out of that starting text color, create this color:
R:168
G:218
B:255

How to achieve that? Which color filter should i use?
Also, is it possible to make it "dynamic" so only part of the text that's currently under semi-transparent "View A" gets new color, while another part of the text view (that's still not fully covered by "View A") is color in starting color?